# Android run time error using OnTouchListenner

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm asking the user to touch TextView1 and need to print the 'x' axis position that he touched on TextView2. However, whenever I touch that TextView1, my app "unfortunately stops"-testing on a device-
this is the class: Part3

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Part3 extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{
    private TextView txtView1;
    private TextView txtView2;
    float x,y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_part3);
        txtView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Part3_txtView1);
        txtView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Part3_txtView2);
        x=0;y=0;
        this.txtView1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.Part3_txtView1){
            x= event.getX();
            y= event.getY();
            txtView2.setText((int)x);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }}
```

This is activity_part3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Part3_txtView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="@string/Part3_s1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Part3_txtView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and LogCat:

```
09-29 15:14:27.043: W/dalvikvm(8454): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x121
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3495)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at bnabaei.touchrecorder.Part3.onTouch(Part3.java:36)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5559)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1785)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1785)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1785)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2058)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1785)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1390)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5766)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-29 15:14:27.063: E/AndroidRuntime(8454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Docs for TextView#setText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) state that it will look for a String resource to set as the text, so where you have said

```
x= event.getX();
y= event.getY();
txtView2.setText((int)x);
```

The system is looking for a resource with resource ID `x`

You should cast `x` to a `String` in order to set the value to the `TextView`

```
textView2.setText(String.valueOf(x));
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much! It works now! Wondering why it wasn't a compile time error?

Comment: technically it isn't a compilation error, there's no way the compiler can know that x isn't going to be the value of a String resource, as the resource IDs can (and do) change